# How to save uploaded pdf,doc,jpg files in a folder using jquery and asp.net (aspx pages)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have tried this but it isn't working as the debugger does not hit web method in c# file. 
C# code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string DocumentUpload()
{

        var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedImage"];
        if (httpPostedFile != null)
        {
            var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DistributorDocument/DistributorEnrollmentDocument/" + HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString()), httpPostedFile.FileName);

            // Save the uploaded file to "UploadedFiles" folder
            httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
        }
        return "";
}
```

Here is the jquery code that I am using while uploading a file. i am trying to upload a file of doc,pdf,jpg type. Please help me as i am new to asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.uploadedFile').on('change', function (e) {

    var documentDescription = '';

    documentDescription = e.target.name.split('.').pop();

    var fileName = "";

    var documentType = $(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    fileName = e.target.files[0].name;

    var data = new FormData();
    var files = $("#" + e.target.id).get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DistributorEnrollmentForm.aspx/DocumentUpload",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var msg = response.d;
            if (msg == "success") {
                $.notify('Data saved successfully', {
                    style: 'happyblue',
                    className: 'superblue'
                });
            }
            $('#uploadDocumentPassport_DL').val('');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            document.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
});
```